# How long can I run car accessories for before my battery goes flat?

Tags: electrical, battery

I have a Hyundai i10 1 litre 2015 model.  The battery it uses is 52ah and 12V.

Given the scenario that the car battery is sufficiently charged after a long drive, the engine is off and I have the following accessories switched on

1. the radio
2. the fan on low (number 1)
3. the in car light
4. a 12V heated car seat

how long would it take before I get a flat battery?

Comment: Theoretically you can draw a maximum of 1 amp for 52 hours, 2 amps for 26 hours, etc. The heated car seat probably draws more than the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to say without knowing exactly how many amps those four accessories draw, and also remember that you need to have sufficient juice left in the battery to crank the engine if you're planning on starting the car again without jumping...

But just for fun, let's say your draw is something like this:

radio: 2 A
blower fan: 4 A
dome light: 500 mA
one heated seat: 5 A

Drawing a total of 11.5 Amps (again, a very very rough guess on my part), your 52 amp hour battery will be entirely drained in (52/11.5) 4.5 hours.